# Imageview element disappers on selecting the link

Tags: java, android

I have a XML file with a imageview as follows. It also has a TextView anmed "linksend".

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    />
```

I have a Java file as as follows

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgview1);  
URL url;
url = new URL(someurlforimage);
Bitmap bmp;
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

TextView tv=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linksend);
tv.append(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+link "\">" +"Press link"+"</a>"));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

The image disappears from the imageview when the html link is pressed. Though the html page opens in a separate browser, the app's image becomes empty.

Comment: Without doing any code how imageview became empty when textview link click ?

Comment: I have no idea. But should the link be in a separate thread ?. If so can u give an example